# Vue js toggle class of each individual element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

While there are many examples of toggling classes in Vuejs, I am yet to find one that toggles a class narrowing down the scope of the element. If I define a global variable like this:

```js
data: {
  toggle: false
}
```

I will run into a problem when I have an element, like this navigation bar:

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="has-dropdown" v-bind:class="{ 'is-open': toggle }" @click="toggle = !toggle">
    Foo
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li>Dropdown Item 1</li>
      <li>Dropdown Item 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="has-dropdown" v-bind:class="{ 'is-open': toggle }" @click="toggle = !toggle">
    Bar
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li>Dropdown Item 1</li>
      <li>Dropdown Item 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

See what happens here? If I click in one of these two elements, both are going to toggle the class at the same time, because it's changing a global variable. Now, how would I toggle the class of *only* the element that is clicked?

Comment: why not create 2 variables in state 1 for each element?

Comment: Each list item should be a child component, then it can store its own toggle state :)

Comment: It would be insanely inconvenient if this is a functionality that needs to be repeated across a large Web site.

Comment: @harrypujols: That's what components are for.

Comment: @SLaks I concur, but seems to me a little over engineering for something that shouldn't be so complicated.

Comment: @harrypujols: No; that's why components are kept very simple.

Comment: Since your 2 dropdowns have the same format, create an array of 2 objects that contains the navigation data, add a `toggle` property to each, and create the template with `v-for`. No need to create a separate component.

Comment: Thanks @EricGuan but the code in the question is simply an example. I've been looking for something more modular.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fundamental guiding principle of VueJS (and most other modern web frameworks) is that everything comes from the model.

You never talk about manipulating the DOM; instead, you make a model that describes the effect you want.

In your case, that means you want two `data` properties, not one.

However, what you should actually do is make each list item its own child component (which will then get its own model).  Use slots to specify different content in each one.

Answer (score 11):

It boggles my mind that something so simple requires so much code using modern frameworks, and it's a reason why JavaScript development is becoming so complex. I resorted to using a plain-old JavaScript listener to solve the matter.

```html
<li class="has-dropdown" @click="toggle">
    ...
</li>
```

```js
...

methods: {
 toggle: function( event ) {
   event.target.classList.toggle('is-open')
 }
}

...
```

Comment: In the next few days, I'll accept the most voted of my peers' answer since mine is not a true "Vue js" answer.

Comment: This could still have two open at once no?

Comment: No @Bert it only toggles the class of the element clicked. This no longer uses "toggle" in data.

Comment: I understand, but if one has the class `is-open` and I click on a different `li` that also has `@click="toggle"` then I could have two `li`s with `is-open`.

Comment: Yes, you would have to click on each one you want to toggle the class to, that's the point.

Comment: Alright, I was misunderstanding that you only ever wanted one with `is-open` at any given time from other comments. :)

Answer (score 7):

This is just a small example of what @SLaks mentioned in his answer. Essentially turn the list elements into their own components so they can have their own state.

```
Vue.component("clicktoggle", {
  template:`<li :class="{ 'is-open': toggle }" @click="toggle = !toggle"><slot></slot></li>`,
  data() {return {toggle: false}}
})
```

And here is how it's used.

```js
console.clear()

Vue.component("clicktoggle", {
  template:`<li :class="{ 'is-open': toggle }" @click="toggle = !toggle"><slot></slot></li>`,
  data() {return {toggle: false}}
})

new Vue({
  el:"#app"
})
```

```css
.has-dropdown {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.has-dropdown:not(.is-open) ul {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="has-dropdown" is="clicktoggle">
      Foo
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li>Dropdown Item 1</li>
        <li>Dropdown Item 2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <clicktoggle class="has-dropdown">
      Bar
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li>Dropdown Item 1</li>
        <li>Dropdown Item 2</li>
      </ul>
    </clicktoggle>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Vue makes it incredibly simple to knock out little components like this. One quick possible enhancement would be to add a property to specify *what* class you wanted to toggle.

Answer (score 2):

the way I handle this is not to use a boolean but a an index (numeric or otherwise). Check if `toggle === index` and on click set toggle to index or to -1

---

here is a working version using string value as toggle

https://jsfiddle.net/dnqp2nc9/1/

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
  toggle: null
  }
})
```

```css
.has-dropdown li{
  opacity: 0.2;
}
.is-open li{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  {{toggle}}
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="has-dropdown" v-bind:class="{ 'is-open': toggle === 'foo' }" @click="toggle = toggle !== 'foo' ? 'foo' : null">
      Foo [{{toggle === 'foo' ? 'open' : 'closed'}}]
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li>Dropdown Item 1</li>
        <li>Dropdown Item 2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-dropdown" v-bind:class="{ 'is-open': toggle === 'bar' }" @click="toggle = toggle !== 'bar' ? 'bar' : null">
      Bar [{{toggle === 'bar' ? 'open' : 'closed'}}]
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li>Dropdown Item 1</li>
        <li>Dropdown Item 2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

to open/close multiple, here is a array version
https://jsfiddle.net/hLm82x1d/1/

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
  toggle: []
  },
  methods: {
   toggleItem: function (key) {
     var i = this.toggle.indexOf(key)
     if (i < 0) {
       this.toggle.push(key)
      } else {
       this.toggle.splice(i, 1)
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.has-dropdown li{
  opacity: 0.2;
}
.is-open li{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  {{toggle}}
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="has-dropdown" v-bind:class="{ 'is-open': toggle.indexOf('foo') >= 0 }" @click="toggleItem('foo')">
      Foo [{{toggle === 'foo' ? 'open' : 'closed'}}]
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li>Dropdown Item 1</li>
        <li>Dropdown Item 2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-dropdown" v-bind:class="{ 'is-open': toggle.indexOf('bar') >= 0 }" @click="toggleItem('bar')">
      Bar [{{toggle === 'bar' ? 'open' : 'closed'}}]
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li>Dropdown Item 1</li>
        <li>Dropdown Item 2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You're assuming that he doesn't want both to be able to open at once.

Comment: In the question sample both already open at once, so the assumption is correct. The point is opening one at a time.

Comment: yes, in the case of mulitple, can be set to add and remove index from an array

Comment: @harrypujols If you want to open one at a time, simply store the index of the one that is opened in data. You don't need to store the states of all the items then.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include some code, just know that this is to illustrate the concept, there are ways to implement this using better practices (such as using computed values and methods)

Answer (score 0):

This seem to have worked for me (Nuxt and Bootstrap 5), idea was to have dropdown as child component that toggles via data, this is still work in progress but it seem to work, I am learning Js and Vue as I go so this might not be the best way to do it.

ThePrimary.vue

```
<template>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <nuxt-link class="navbar-brand" to="/">Navbar</nuxt-link>
      <button
        @click="isNavbarCollapsed = !isNavbarCollapsed"
        ref="navbar-toggler"
        :aria-expanded="[!isNavbarCollapsed ? 'true' : 'false']"
        :class="{ collapsed: isNavbarCollapsed}"
        class="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
        aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation"
      >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div 
        :class="{ show: !isNavbarCollapsed}"
        class="collapse navbar-collapse" 
        id="navbarNavDropdown"
      >
        <NavbarNav :items="loadedPrimaryMenu" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</template>

<script>
import NavbarNav from '@/components/Navigation/ThePrimary/NavbarNav'

export default {
  name: 'TheNavigationPrimary',
  data() {
    return {
      isNavbarCollapsed: true
    }
  },
  computed: {
    loadedPrimaryMenu() {
      return this.$store.getters.loadedPrimaryMenu
    }
  },
  components: {
    NavbarNav
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">


</style>
```

NavbarNav.vue

```
 <template>
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li
      v-for="item in items"
      :key="item.id"
      class="nav-item"
      :class="{ dropdown: hasChildren(item.children) }"
    >
      <NavLink
        v-if="!hasChildren(item.children)" 
        :attributes="item"
      />
      <NavbarNavDropdownMenu
        v-else
        :item="item"
      />
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
import NavbarNavDropdownMenu from "@/components/Navigation/ThePrimary/NavbarNavDropdownMenu";
import NavLink from '@/components/Navigation/NavLink';

export default {
  name: "NavbarNav",
  props: {
    items: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
    };
  },
  methods: {
    hasChildren(item) {
      return item.length > 0 ? true : false;
    },
  },
  components: {
    NavbarNavDropdownMenu,
    NavLink
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">

</style>
```

NavbarNavDropdownMenu.vue

```
<template>
  <span v-if="item">
    <nuxt-link
      to="#"
      @click.prevent.native="openDropdownMenu"
      v-click-outside="closeDropdownMenu"
      :title="item.title"
      :class="[
        item.cssClasses, 
        { show: isDropdownMenuVisible }
      ]"
      :id="`navbarDropdownMenuLink-${item.id}`"
      :aria-expanded="[isDropdownMenuVisible ? true : false]"
      class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
      aria-current="page"
      role="button"
      data-toggle="dropdown"
    >
      {{ item.label }}
    </nuxt-link>
    <ul
      :class="{ show: isDropdownMenuVisible }"
      :aria-labelledby="`navbarDropdownMenuLink-${item.id}`"
      class="dropdown-menu"
    >
      <li v-for="item in item.children" :key="item.id">
        <NavLink
          :attributes="item"
          class="dropdown-item"
        />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </span>
</template>

<script>
import NavLink from '@/components/Navigation/NavLink';

export default {
  name: "DropdownMenu",
  props: {
    item: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      isDropdownMenuVisible: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    openDropdownMenu() {
      this.isDropdownMenuVisible = !this.isDropdownMenuVisible;
    },

    closeDropdownMenu() {
        this.isDropdownMenuVisible = false;
    }
  },
  components: {
    NavLink
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">

</style>
```

NavLink.vue

```
 <template>
  <component
    v-bind="linkProps(attributes.path)"
    :is="attributes"  
    :title="attributes.title"
    :class="[ attributes.cssClasses ]"
    class="nav-link active"
    aria-current="page"
    prefetch
  >
  {{ attributes.label }}
  </component>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'NavLink',
  props: {
    attributes: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    linkProps (path) {
      if (path.match(/^(http(s)?|ftp):\/\//) || path.target === '_blank') {
        return {
          is: 'a',
          href: path,
          target: '_blank',
          rel: 'noopener'
        }
      }
      return {
        is: 'nuxt-link',
        to: path
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">

</style>
```

To close dropdown on click outside

```
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.directive('click-outside', {
  bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
    el.clickOutsideEvent = function (event) {
      if (!(el == event.target || el.contains(event.target))) {
        vnode.context[binding.expression](event);
      }
    };
    document.body.addEventListener('click', el.clickOutsideEvent)
  },
  unbind: function (el) {
    document.body.removeEventListener('click', el.clickOutsideEvent)
  },
});
```